How do I generate a sequence of numbers with unpredictable differences
This question relates to bit flip attacks on OTP encrypted messages.
Lets say I've got a list of numbers from 0 to 2^24-1
I want to re-order the list so it has the following property:
If you start at a random (unknown) position and go forward 1 step, I want it to be as hard as possible to guess how the the value will change. Assuming the re-ordered list is known. The list is circular.
Edit: By changes I mean "which bits in the value will flip". To put it another way:

Attacker knows value from list AFTER OTP is applied (they don't know the actual value)
Attacker does something which they know will cause the list position to step forward 1.
Attacker wants to guess what the new value will be AFTER OTP.

Examples:

For a simple ordered sequence 1,2,3,4... It's quite easy. If you go
forward one step in the sequence, 50% of the time this will cause
only the LSB to toggle. Chance of correct guess: 1/2

I tried a few completely random sequences and found the most common
changes occurred 9-10 times. Chance of correct guess: 10/2^24.

1/2^24 would be considered "perfect". Since that's the base chance of guessing without knowing anything.


So my question is. How would I go about choosing the order to maximize the difficulty of this guess.
Edit2: I will try to describe the problem using the notation from the comments.

Start with a list of all possible values for a 24 bit number, in
order. 0,1,2,3, etc. We will call this list U.

We will re-order this list in some way, generating list V.

An index in the list is chosen at random. We will call this i.

An attacker has access to V, but not i

The attacker must guess the value Vi⊕V(i+1modn)

The goal is to modify the list in such a way as to maximize the difficulty of this guess.


Some thoughts: To achieve 1/2^24, each difference would have to appear exactly once. I'm not sure that's even possible.

Err Drew, I think that you might have to reword this question as it's difficult to understand what you're after exactly.  Soz.

The question seems clear enough to me: We want a public probabilistic polynomial time algorithm which on input a vector $U$ of $n>0$ values $u_i$ of $b=24$ bits, generates a reordered list $V$ of values $v_i$, such that the probability of an attacker guessing $v_i⊕v_{(i+1\bmod n)}$ knowing $U$ is minimized. We can assume that probability is averaged over all indexes $i∈[0,n)$ (or equivalently, for a random secret $i$; and nearly equivalently for $i=0$, if we end the algorithm with a rotation by a random secret value). Update: but it's unclear if if $u_i=u_j⟹i=j$, and if $n=2^b$.

@fgrieu as I read the question the adversary actually knows $V$. But it is indeed unclear if the list is the input or we only need to find an order for $[0, 2^b)$

@CommandMaster: If we read « Assuming the list is known » to mean that $V$ is known, then if $i$ is known, an attacker can guess $v_i⊕v_{(i+1\bmod n)}$ with certainty. And 1/2/3 strongly suggests that an attacker knows $i$ (because to alter a ciphertext, an attacker must know where they make that alteration). That's why I'm reading « Assuming the list is known » to mean that $U$ is known, not $V$.

I interpreted it as $V$ being known and $i$ not, but what you're saying does make sense. OP, could you clarify?

The problem as I read it is nontrivial. Performing a random shuffling is not optimal. For example, with $n=4$, and the list $U=(0,1,0,1)$ the algorithm should generate $(0,0,1,1)$ or $(0,1,1,0)$ or $(1,1,0,0)$ or $(1,0,0,1)$ with probability $1/4$ each, yielding a probability at most $1/2$ of successful guess (for either of the guesses $0$ or $1$). Whereas for random shuffling the guess $1$ yields a higher probability of correct guess (I think $2/3$).

@CommandMaster Yes I believe that's correct. The attacker knows the list after it has been reordered (which I think fgrieu has denoted as V). But the attacker does not know the current location in the list (which I think he is referring to as i).

The way I see it is that "minimize repeated differences" is incompatible with "maximize the difficulty of this guess".  The former is number of bits via XOR, whilst the latter is a probability.  I've been here before, and I find that after several edits it's more productive to completely re-write the question from scratch...

@PaulUszak I just removed that part. My interpretation is that reducing the number of change patterns that occur multiple times would be the best way to make the guess difficult, but maybe I'm mistaken about that.

Let $U=\{v(0),v(1),\ldots,v(2^n-1)\}$ where $v(k)$ is the binary vector representing the integer $n,$ and each $v(i) \in \{0,1\}^n,$ which we can take as $GF(2)^n$ for convenience.
Almost Perfect Nonlinear functions.
A function $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$ is APN if the multiset
$$\{f(x)\oplus f(x\oplus a): 
x \in \{0,1\}^n\},$$
has half the possible vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$ occur twice (hence another half are missing). By symmetry if $f(x)=f(x\oplus a)\oplus f(x)$ then $x'=x\oplus a$ is also a solution of the equation so we always get 2 solutions in characteristic 2 (i.e., binary arithmetic) and this is the best possible, perfect distribution of differences is impossible in binary.
That means the difference with the next value is equidistributed on half the possible values, which is quite good, since you choose the point i at random and this holds for all $i$.
Here we wish to have $n=m.$ Unfortunately, we must have $n$ odd for an APN permutation to exist. For example, the map $x\mapsto x^{2^n-2}$ which is used in AES Sbox for $n=8$ is APN for any $n$ which is odd.
Therefore, if you were ready to use $n=23$ or $n=25$ you'd be done and get the APN property.
I demonstrate this with the magma script below for $n=3$. You can  run it at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/
I know SageMath and pari/gp can also do the same but magma is what I am familiar with. See here for more.
Since $x^7=1$ for all $x$ in $GF(2^3)$ (multiplicative group has order 7 and thus all elements have order dividing 7) the map usually shown as the inverse map for nonzero elements is actually $x\mapsto x^6.$

K:=GF(2); F:=ext<K|3>; F;


"list of field elements";


[u: u in F];


"corresponding vectors";


[Eltseq(u): u in F];


"list of XORs of vectors with the next element";


[Eltseq(u+u^6): u in F];


"permutation you want";


[Eltseq(u^6): u in F];

Output is below with probability of correctly guessing the next element being $1/2^{n-1}.$

Oops, here is the permutation you want listed:
[
[ 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 1, 0, 0 ],
[ 1, 0, 1 ],
[ 1, 1, 1 ],
[ 0, 1, 1 ],
[ 1, 1, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 1 ],
[ 0, 1, 0 ]
]
References: Alex Pott has a nice set of slides here with definition but is focused on finding non-power APN permutations, i.e., not of the form $x\mapsto x^d$ which are very rare.  Claude Carlet has a whole Chapter  on related topics see here.

Thanks! I don't fully understand all the math yet, but I from what I do understand I believe this is the answer. Will keep working on it.
